# Selenium: get coordinates or dimensions of element with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I see that there are methods for getting the screen position and dimensions of an element through various Java libraries for Selenium, such as `org.openqa.selenium.Dimension`, which offers `.getSize()`, and `org.openqa.selenium.Point` with `getLocation()`.

Is there any way to get either the location or dimensions of an element with the Selenium Python bindings?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Got it! The clue was on [selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement — Selenium 3.14 documentation.](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html)

WebElements have the properties `.size` and `.location`. Both are of type `dict`.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//someXpath")

location = e.location
size = e.size
w, h = size['width'], size['height']

print(location)
print(size)
print(w, h)
```

Output:

```
{'y': 202, 'x': 165}
{'width': 77, 'height': 22}
77 22
```

They also have a property called [`rect`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.rect) which is itself a `dict`, and contains the element's `size` and `location`.

Comment: How to achieve this in C#? I want to get the bounds of an element and then do some calculation and click using x, y coordinates on that element.

Comment: @rahoolm you can just do `e.click()` and selenium will click on it.

Comment: What do these coordinates mean? They are different from the location of the element on the screen, at least on my machine. Are they relative to the browser window size?

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what i need, in my case i can't click in a checkbox usign Chrome headless mode, so i'm trying to figure it whats happening and whats the actual position of the element..

Comment: How can I extract x and y coordinates from this (element.location())?

I need the x and y coordinates indivisually.

Comment: @ePandit , the returned object is a dictionary in all language bindings, as the answer clearly states, just access values as you normally do for dictionary/collection classes natively. Note that the actual location is going to be relative, you may want to inspect the entire DOM just using the browser "inspect" popup menu.