# How to get Selenium's IWebElement position in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried to find a way how to get the IWebElement's position (images in particular) and use it in my C# tests. So far the [only example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510882/selenium-get-coordinates-or-dimensions-of-element-with-python) I was able to dig in is in Python. Is there such org.openqa.selenium.Dimension equivalence for C# ?

Comment: Hope [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/Properties_T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement.htm) is what u r looking for...

Comment: Not quite, but I guess the combination of  IWebElement.Location and  IWebElement.Size will do the trick. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Well that's precisely how the other language bindings would have you do it too and it's how it's shown in your linked question also - a combination of the location & size.

Comment: I was kinda looking for an encapsulated solution, but I'll wrap it my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this JS code:

```
$('#<element id>').position().top.toString() + ',' + $('#<element id>').position().left.toString()
```