# How to find coordinates(x, y) of checkbox with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox

I would like to find the position (x, y) of a checkbox, but unfortunately after several searches I have not found solutions ... (Even following the instructions in this answer: [Selenium: get coordinates or dimensions of element with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510882/selenium-get-coordinates-or-dimensions-of-element-with-python))

Here is my code:

```
E = wait (browser, 20) .until (EC.element_to_be_clickable ((By.ID, 'recaptcha-anchor')))
Location = E.location
Print Location
```

Unfortunately, this action returns me coordinates not going towards the direction of the checkbox in question ...

Did you have a solution, or is it really impossible to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: be careful with the case of variables, locate or Locate

Comment: Sure enough, but that does not change my problem