# Verify size and coordinates in Selenium

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, coordinates

I have a question - did Python + Selenium give the opportunity to verify size and coordinates on the web-page?

I mean I have a mockup in Figma with the size of the element and his coordinates. And I want to know can I verify these values by Python + Selenium on the Web Page?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Maybe we can't use Figma, but maybe you can verify coordinates in the browser, and then write them in the test-cases?

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: I hope you will find this helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510882/selenium-get-coordinates-or-dimensions-of-element-with-python

Comment: rahul rai - I don't need to know coordinates. I need to verify coordinates in Python code with coordinates on Web, so they should be exact same