# Python: How can I get current mouse co-ordinates in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the current mouse location after an action in Selenium (click, move, page reload etc). Is there any way to do it and return the values to Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601097/how-to-get-the-mouse-position-without-events-without-moving-the-mouse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium: get coordinates or dimensions of element with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510882/selenium-get-coordinates-or-dimensions-of-element-with-python)

Comment: @JoranBeasley - Although I can add JS to Selenium, I haven't found a way just yet to return the values on Event. When I tried, the variables returned undefined.

Comment: @vitaliis: I am not moving to an element, I am moving by offset without knowledge on which element I'm landing on. I know it's not the conventional way how Selenium is used but this is the way I have to use it for the sake of the problem being solved.

Comment: the answer is NO there is no way to get the currentMousePosition ... in theory you could make a `document.on('mousemove` listener and update some global javascript variable(but it will only do anything when the mouse actually moves which doesnt usually happen with a selenium script) ...   but this sounds like an XY problem... why do you think you need to get the mouse position?